MSDataSetGenerator generates references to obsolete type NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.TimestampTZ
Like the title says, in my .Net Core 8 project, MSDataSetGenerator generates references to obsolete type TimestampTZ instead of TimestampTz (note the case difference!).  Every time I change my .xsd file, I have to search/replace TimestampTZ for TimestampTz to compile.
The pgsql columns are timestamp with time zone.
Example generated code for column, created_date:
        param = new global::Npgsql.NpgsqlParameter();
        param.ParameterName = "@created_date";
        param.DbType = global::System.Data.DbType.DateTimeOffset;
        param.NpgsqlDbType = global::NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.TimestampTZ; // <-- OBSOLETE REFERENCE!!!
        param.IsNullable = true;
        param.SourceColumn = "created_date";

Relevant tool and package versions:

Npgsql 8.0.3
Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL 8.0.4
Microsoft.EntittyFrameworkCore 8.0.6
Microsoft.EntittyFrameworkCore.Relational 8.0.6
Visual Studio 17.10.3

